# How to unmarshal command line input properly?

Tags: json, go, command-line-arguments

I have written following code snippet in `trial.go`:

```
type Mine struct{
    A string `json:"a"`
}

func main(){
    s := Mine{}
    v := os.Args[1]//`{"a":"1"}`
    fmt.Println(v)
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(v))
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(v), &s)
    fmt.Println(s)  
}
```

I am running this file as below:

```
go run trial.go `{"A":"1"}`
```

But I don't get anything in `s`. It is always a blank struct.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you try checking the error from Unmarshal?

Comment: Different errors actually like "invalid character 'A' looking for beginning of object key string" but i guess the answer given by @icza worked for me. Although i get a feeling now that command line input would not be good option for me when i try to use above code snippet into a larger one where i expect larger input strings. I need to find a better way of accepting input.

Comment: I think you should pass only {"A":"1"} without back ticks ``

Comment: @YandryPozo already tried that but it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check errors returned by [`json.Unmarshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal).

Next your `json` tag uses small `"a"` as the JSON key, however the [`encoding/json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) package will recognize the capital `"A"` too.

And last passing such arguments in the command line may be OS (shell) specific. The backtick and quotes usually have special meaning, try passing it like this:

```
go run trial.go {\"a\":\"1\"}
```

Also you should check the length of `os.Args` before indexing it, if the user does not provide any arguments, `os.Args[1]` will panic.

As you mentioned, you should find another way to test input JSON documents, this becomes unfeasible if the JSON text is larger, and also this is OS (shell) specific. A better way would be to read from the standard input or read from a file.